# Cannot add a configuration with name 'developmentOnly' as a configuration with that name already exists for Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to add the io.micronaut.application plugin to my application, but the build is failing with error.

```
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 4

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.micronaut.application', version: '3.7.2']
> Failed to apply plugin class 'io.micronaut.gradle.MicronautMinimalApplicationPlugin'.
   > Cannot add a configuration with name 'developmentOnly' as a configuration with that name already exists.
```

```
...
plugins {
    id 'io.micronaut.application' version '3.7.2'
}

apply plugin: "application"
...
...
```

Also, there is no developmentOnly configuration explicitly defined in the build.gradle

I tried getting the dependency tree to check if there are dependencies under the developmentOnly configuration, but there is nothing in that too

```
developmentOnly - Configuration for development-only dependencies such as Spring Boot's DevTools.
No dependencies
```

Is there a way to get around this?

I am using Java 17 with Gradle 7.5

Comment: please provide the complete build file

Answer (score 0):

You already applied the plugin in the `plugins` block, just delete the explicit `apply` statement